# Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'FILE*'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

When I compile this code, I get the error

```
**[Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'FILE* {aka _iobuf*}' [-fpermissive]**
```

Code:

```
int yazi;
FILE *dosya;
char *girdi = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*500);

void cikiskayit()
{
    HWND pencere;
    pencere = NULL;

    int mesajkutu = MessageBox(
         pencere,
         "Yazıyı kaydetmek istermisiniz ?",
         "Kayıt ?",
         MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_YESNO);

    if (mesajkutu == 1)
    {
        dosya = fprintf(dosya,girdi);    // error's source line  
    }
    else if(mesajkutu == 2)
    {
        fclose(dosya);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tighten up the code and give more details as to how you compiled it (compiler, flags, et cetera)? A complete, compilable example is much easier for people to answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**fprintf** returns the number of characters printed.  For some reason, you're trying to assign this to a variable whose type is FILE*.  This is not allowed.

Without meaningful variable names or comments, I can't really help you beyond this -- I don't know how to fix it for you.  I suspect that you just want to drop the assignment portion and only call **printf**.